# When I create a singleton class and configure it in spring configuarion file with prototype scope, it lets me create multiple instances of that class

Tags: java, spring, singleton

Is this the expected behavior? I mean I know I should not declare its scope as prototype but shouldn't Spring give me an error at run time? Is this happening because I do not have checks in my singleton for reflection thing?

**Singleton class:-**
public class Stage {

```
static Stage stage=null;
private Stage(){};

private static Stage stageHolder(){
    stage= new Stage();
    return stage;
}

public static Stage getStage(){
    stage=stageHolder();
    System.out.println("setting stage "+stage.hashCode());
    return stage;
}
```

}

**Configuration file:-**
bean id="stage" class="springinaction.springinaction.Stage" factory-method="getStage" scope="prototype"

**calling java class:-**
Stage stage= (Stage)ac.getBean("stage");
Stage stage1= (Stage)ac.getBean("stage");

**result:-**
setting stage 117417953**
setting stage 2053548125
** hashcode of created instance

Comment: how is the getStage method implemente? may you provide some code of Stage bean?

Comment: @AngeloImmediata Sure. I've added code of Stage bean in the question.

Comment: Well, your getStage() method creates a new Stage every time it's called. So it isn't very surprising. You got your singleton wrong.

Comment: If you need a singleton of the `Stage` class, declare it as an Spring bean and use it wherever you want. That's the default scope for the beans, don't need to worry about managing the singleton instance yourself.

Comment: @JBNizet oops. Yup it's returning same hashcode after correcting the singleton. Thanks.